# If 3 six faced fair dice are thrown together, then the probability that the sum of the numbers $ 9\leqslant k \leqslant 14$

Tags: probability

If 3 six faced fair dice are thrown together, then the probability that the sum of the numbers appearing on the dice is k where $ 9\leqslant k \leqslant 14$ is  :

My approach : Possible sum values are from 3 to 18 and our cases of interst are $9,10,11,12,13,14 \therefore$ probability should be $\frac{6}{16}$ but the answer given is $\frac{21k-k^{2}-83}{216}$ How can arrive at the given answer ?

Comment: You need a solution for each of the $k$, and not for the sum.

Comment: This is not clear.  first of all, not all sums are equally likely ($3$ can only be obtained as $\{1,1,1\}$ but there are lots of ways to get a $10$, say).  But, more seriously, if the official answer has a $k$ in it then that answer must hold for $k$ alone.  You have to compute the probabilities of getting each of the $6$ values and then confirm that this quadratic matches your values.

Comment: $\frac6{15}$ is wrong: there are $16$ possible sums, but they are not equally likely.  The denominator should be $216$ or a divisor of it.

Comment: Let this example be a reminder that $Pr(E)=\frac{|E|}{|S|}$ is **only** valid when our sample space is **unbiased** (*every outcome in the sample space is equally likely to occur*).  Taking the sample space as the possible summations for this problem will not work since these are not equally likely outcomes.  You could however take the sample space as all results of the three dice if the dice were differently colored:  $\{(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),\dots,(2,1,1)\dots,(6,6,4),(6,6,5),(6,6,6)\}$.

Comment: Even it probability were equally likely, 3..18 are 16 outcomes ;)

Comment: @Henry Sorry, 15 was a typo. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Consider only Sum of all outcomes to be 9.
Then see the cases where when 3 fair dices are thrown, the sum comes out to be 9. There will be 25 such cases when checked.

Means probability will be 25/216.

With this knowledge, put k=9 in the given equations. The equation which will give the same output is the answer. Thus, equation with 21k-k^2-83 as numerator satisfies our requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Every roll of three dice corresponds to an ordered triple $(D_1, D_2, D_3)$, where $1 \leq D_i \leq 6$ for each $1 \leq i \leq 3$. There are $6^3 = 216$ such ordered triples, which make up our sample space: $$\Omega := \{(D_1, D_2, D_3):\text{for each } 1 \leq i \leq 3, D_i \in \Bbb{N} \text{ and } 1 \leq D_i \leq 6 \} .$$ Therefore the probability we want to find, $$\Bbb{P}( D_1 + D_2 + D_3 = k ) \text{ for } k \in \Bbb{N} \text{ and } 3 \leq k \leq 18,$$ must have a denominator of $216$, if we write it as $$\Bbb{P}( D_1 + D_2 + D_3 = k ) = \frac{|E_k|}{|\Omega|},$$ where $E_k \subset \Omega$ is the set $$E_k := \{(D_1, D_2, D_3):\text{for each } 1 \leq i \leq 3, D_i \in \Bbb{N}, 1 \leq D_i \leq 6, \text{ and } D_1 + D_2 + D_3 = k \}.$$

Because $$(D_1, D_2, D_3) \in E_k$$ is equivalent to $$(7 - D_1, 7 - D_2, 7 - D_3) \in E_{21 - k},$$ we have $|E_k| = |E_{21-k}|$, so it suffices to evaluate $$E_3, E_4, ..., E_9, E_{10},$$ as we will then know the values of $$E_{18} = E_3, E_{17} = E_4, ..., E_{12} = E_9, E_{11} = E_{10}.$$ An application of [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) then gives us $$E_k = \binom{k-1}{2} - 3\binom{k-7}{2} = \frac{-2k^2+42k-166}{2} = -k^2+21k-83 = k(21-k) - 83$$ for $3 \leq k \leq 10$.

(*The second term comes from excluding partitions of $k$ that have at least one part $>6$. We can partition $k-6$ into a sum of three positive integers in $\binom{k-7}{2}$ ways, and then we have $3$ choices of which positive integer to add $6$ back to to get a partition of $k$ where one part is strictly greater than $6$. This gives a total of $3\binom{k-7}{2}$ such partitions of $k$.*)

This matches the original numerator when $k = 9, 10$. Since the quadratic $f(x) = x(21-x) - 83$ satisfies $f(x) = f(21-x)$, we know that this formula works for $k = 11, 12, 13, 14$ as well. Done.